# Failed to get existing code hash, continue without duplicate check... on set contract

Tags: eosio.cdt

### Update 12/17/18:

I solved this by updating my CDT to latest.  Still unsure what the issue was.

---

OS: Windows with Linux/Ubuntu Sub Module

Nodeos: v1.5

CDT: v1.3.2

---

So I'm trying to set a simple contract.

Contract:

```
#include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp>
#include <string>

using namespace eosio;

class [[eosio::contract]] hello : public eosio::contract {
  public:
   using contract::contract;

   hello(name receiver, name code,  datastream<const char*> ds): contract(receiver, code, ds) {}

      [[eosio::action]]
      void hi( name user ) {
         require_recipient(user);
      }
};

EOSIO_DISPATCH( hello, (hi))
```

Compile contract command used:

```
eosio-cpp -o hello.wasm hello.cpp --abigen
Warning, empty ricardian clause file
Warning, empty ricardian clause file
Warning, action <hi> does not have a ricardian contract
```

ABI:

```
{
    "____comment": "This file was generated with eosio-abigen. DO NOT EDIT Fri Dec 14 06:53:47 2018",
    "version": "eosio::abi/1.1",
    "structs": [
        {
            "name": "hi",
            "base": "",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "name": "user",
                    "type": "name"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "types": [],
    "actions": [
        {
            "name": "hi",
            "type": "hi",
            "ricardian_contract": ""
        }
    ],
    "tables": [],
    "ricardian_clauses": [],
    "variants": [],
    "abi_extensions": []
}
```

And I'm getting the error:

```
Failed to get existing code hash, continue without duplicate check...
Reading WASM from /mnt/c/Workspaces/new_eos/my_contracts/hello/hello.wasm...
Publishing contract...
Error 3090003: Provided keys, permissions, and delays do not satisfy declared authorizations
```

However, I have both the eosio key and the host contract's key in my wallet.

[image]

Here's the succesful command coming back from creating the account:

```
cleos create account eosio hellohellohe EOS8gG7oywSuTFBZ6aYqLUKkz4dfJbjBUbieVhzM7EVamoUGLnW2u EOS8gG7oywSuTFBZ6aYqLUKkz4dfJbjBUbieVhzM7EVamoUGLnW2u
executed transaction: 76157e4c6d965e48fb9713eb8c3b3f431825059e5c6bd887b8df847cc44893d0  200 bytes  256 us
#         eosio <= eosio::newaccount            {"creator":"eosio","name":"hellohellohe","owner":{"threshold":1,"keys":[{"key":"EOS8gG7oywSuTFBZ6aYq...
warning: transaction executed locally, but may not be confirmed by the network yet         ]
```

Full request/response and cleos call:

- POST /v1/chain/get_code_hash HTTP/1.0
- RESPONSE: Code 500 Internal Service Error "Failed to get existing code hash, continue without duplicate
  check... Reading WASM from
  /mnt/c/Workspaces/new_eos/my_contracts/hello/hello.wasm... Publishing
  contract..."
- POST /v1/chain/get_info HTTP/1.0 RES: Looks good there
- POST /v1/wallet/get_public_keys HTTP/1.0 RES: Looks good there, got
  the keys
- POST /v1/chain/get_required_keys HTTP/1.0 with really big data object

---

```
cleos --print-request --print-response  set contract hellohellohe hello hello.wasm hello.abi -p hellohellohe

REQUEST:

POST /v1/chain/get_code_hash HTTP/1.0
Host: 127.0.0.1:8888
content-length: 36
Accept: */*
Connection: close

{
  "account_name": "hellohellohe"
}

RESPONSE:

{
  "code": 500,
  "message": "Internal Service Error",
  "error": {
    "code": 0,
    "name": "exception",
    "what": "unspecified",
    "details": []
  }
}

Failed to get existing code hash, continue without duplicate check...
Reading WASM from /mnt/c/Workspaces/new_eos/my_contracts/hello/hello.wasm...
Publishing contract...
REQUEST:

POST /v1/chain/get_info HTTP/1.0
Host: 127.0.0.1:8888
content-length: 0
Accept: */*
Connection: close


RESPONSE:

{
  "server_version": "ea08cfd3",
  "chain_id": "cf057bbfb72640471fd910bcb67639c22df9f92470936cddc1ade0e2f2e7dc4f",
  "head_block_num": 4399,
  "last_irreversible_block_num": 4398,
  "last_irreversible_block_id": "0000112e58be9d3e943c2a0f40437a0ea031aecb2f97b1cf79dd94b999f09250",
  "head_block_id": "0000112fdbfe196288eafc1b3a0909190d2f97d6ec4d501d4bbcd81cb653477c",
  "head_block_time": "2018-12-14T11:48:56.500",
  "head_block_producer": "eosio",
  "virtual_block_cpu_limit": 16253004,
  "virtual_block_net_limit": 85384710,
  "block_cpu_limit": 199900,
  "block_net_limit": 1048576,
  "server_version_string": "v1.5.0"
}
---------------------
REQUEST:
---------------------
POST /v1/wallet/get_public_keys HTTP/1.0
Host: /home/natanaelprudhomme/eosio-wallet/keosd.sock:
content-length: 0
Accept: */*
Connection: close



RESPONSE:

[
  "EOS5QaqpbQtA98cBbYwhK49wdm2Qdhf7x4hYHb9WkvrSLUNxWm995",
  "EOS5WgXLzLwTXKeRGQV3BSn1saGtT4bkA8jbfLc4L1uTPb9sN6UAw",
  "EOS63zNBrWgKWp2P9pqL5vvKWRdUtJX9tznamw8MkxVSeMGgWYVD5",
  "EOS67wLi78ak2fqffpvGedNqRTEcEeNTZhKBxM3n3cgjBwGerEZgv",
  "EOS6MRyAjQq8ud7hVNYcfnVPJqcVpscN5So8BhtHuGYqET5GDW5CV",
  "EOS7dsJbPAhRCjTwPB28nithDunNZ1oCMTNRC8g31Y3oahx3w62z8",
  "EOS7jEjKydV7Ve7KbkLNbC6WYpTEqCy7KU8asuWJNu1e3qsGYmic2",
  "EOS85wQgYFL2GnU368P3PVDShMpcqcXTVd1JpLBNTMt5jMEBUBUhv",
  "EOS8DEzBSBrYTJu5GdnsN5oJm5QHPT4zqgLGcPuZuc8Xgfib31Xux",
  "EOS8gG7oywSuTFBZ6aYqLUKkz4dfJbjBUbieVhzM7EVamoUGLnW2u"
]

REQUEST:

POST /v1/chain/get_required_keys HTTP/1.0
Host: 127.0.0.1:8888
content-length: 11847
Accept: */*
Connection: close

{
  "transaction": {
    "expiration": "2018-12-14T11:49:26",
    "ref_block_num": 4398,
    "ref_block_prefix": 254426260,
    "max_net_usage_words": 0,
    "max_cpu_usage_ms": 0,
    "delay_sec": 0,
    "context_free_actions": [],
    "actions": [{
        "account": "eosio",
        "name": "setcode",
        "authorization": [{
            "actor": "hellohellohe",
            "permission": "active"
          }
        ],
        "data": "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"
      },{
        "account": "eosio",
        "name": "setabi",
        "authorization": [{
            "actor": "hellohellohe",
            "permission": "active"
          }
        ],
        "data": "a01a8d51351aa36a3e0e656f73696f3a3a6162692f312e31000102686900020475736572046e616d65046e616d6506737472696e6701000000000000806b026869000000000000"
      }
    ],
    "transaction_extensions": []
  },
  "available_keys": [
    "EOS5QaqpbQtA98cBbYwhK49wdm2Qdhf7x4hYHb9WkvrSLUNxWm995",
    "EOS5WgXLzLwTXKeRGQV3BSn1saGtT4bkA8jbfLc4L1uTPb9sN6UAw",
    "EOS63zNBrWgKWp2P9pqL5vvKWRdUtJX9tznamw8MkxVSeMGgWYVD5",
    "EOS67wLi78ak2fqffpvGedNqRTEcEeNTZhKBxM3n3cgjBwGerEZgv",
    "EOS6MRyAjQq8ud7hVNYcfnVPJqcVpscN5So8BhtHuGYqET5GDW5CV",
    "EOS7dsJbPAhRCjTwPB28nithDunNZ1oCMTNRC8g31Y3oahx3w62z8",
    "EOS7jEjKydV7Ve7KbkLNbC6WYpTEqCy7KU8asuWJNu1e3qsGYmic2",
    "EOS85wQgYFL2GnU368P3PVDShMpcqcXTVd1JpLBNTMt5jMEBUBUhv",
    "EOS8DEzBSBrYTJu5GdnsN5oJm5QHPT4zqgLGcPuZuc8Xgfib31Xux",
    "EOS8gG7oywSuTFBZ6aYqLUKkz4dfJbjBUbieVhzM7EVamoUGLnW2u"
  ]
}

RESPONSE:

{
  "code": 401,
  "message": "UnAuthorized",
  "error": {
    "code": 3090003,
    "name": "unsatisfied_authorization",
    "what": "Provided keys, permissions, and delays do not satisfy declared authorizations",
    "details": []
  }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Try this command to create account...may be this can remove your error....`cleos set account permission <your-account-name> active '{"threshold":1,"keys":[{"key":"<you-public-eos-key>","weight":1}],"accounts":[{"permission":{"actor":"<your-account-name>","permission":"eosio.code"},"weight":1}]}' owner -p <your-account-name>@owner`

Comment: *to set permissions not to create account

Comment: Sorry I didn't get around to testing that. Also, theres a much easier way to set code now: `cleos set account permission addressbook active --add-code` https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/inline-actions

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its a permission issue or @eosio.code issue(especially if the contract isn't published)

Maybe you could try something like this in cleos?

cleos --print-request --print-response  set contract hellohellohe hello.wasm hello.abi -p hellohellohe@active

or

cleos --print-request --print-response set contract hellohellohe /directory/of/hello -p hellohellohe@active

Comment: I updated and the problem went away.  Thank you for your answer.